# Not work. wget and block

Tags: ruby, wget

I want to write a script which downloads all the podcasts from an rss-feed.
This is code does not work:

```
  def wget
    @mp3_links.each do |m|
      system("wget", "#{m}")
    end
  end
```

I understand that to be linked to the delay, but how?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain a bit more about why the script does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Google translate?

Anyway, try

```
system("wget ", "#{m}")
#           ^ extra space here
```